# Can AGV transport be blocked by Agents or pedestrians?

Tags: anylogic, agent

I'm currently investigating AGVs in an environment with pedestrian and trying to simulate it in anylogic.

Now the questions arise if there is a method to  let the pedestrians in the environment be agents instead of the pedestrian flows of Anylogic and block the AGVs. So when the pedestrians are using the paths, it will block the AGVs driving on that or the AGV will lower his speed and see it as an obstacle, cause I'm currently practicing with it and when I make the persons an agent, the AGVs just override the persons when it is walking on the AGVs travel path and does not see it as an obstacle.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is unfortunately, no. Quoting AnyLogic help:
By default, path-guided transporters recognize only transporters of the same type as obstacles.

Pedestrians are ignored by transporters moving in free space mode, which means the transporters will run over these shapes during model execution.

Long answer:
You can use road traffic library together with pedestrian library as a workaround. If your pedestrian movements are not chaotic (i.e. they just don't cross the road whenever they want), you can define one or more pedestrian crossing areas and regulate them by using the traffic lights. Similar example is explained here: https://www.anylogic.fr/resources/educational-videos/simulating-a-pedestrian-crossing/

Comment: Also check my blog post on the topic (same philosophy): https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2016/5/30/how-to-get-pedestrians-and-road-traffic-like-each-other-in-anylogic

Comment: Thank you both for your answer! To make things more clear, it is all about an hospital environment in which unfortunately pedestrians will not wait crossing a road. When looking at the blog of Benjamin, perhaps the second option could work, only there will be around 10.000 pedestrians in the environment, continuously checking if there are pedestrian near an agent will probably take a lot of power

Comment: Seriously consider your model design, 10k peds are often not needed to solve your actual model problem. Only use peds when and where they are needed, else use normal agents only!